# How to make a "0000001" NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Another noob question from me.
I'm trying to create an application that counts, and I'd like to display the number value as something like "000001". So when it counts up it'll display as "000002".

I'm using something like this right now, but it's not working:

```
counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%000f", count];
```

The counter.text is a UILabel.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're storing the number as an integer, use the `%0xd` format (where `x` is the number of digits) like so:

```
counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%06d", count];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSLog(@"%.6d",3);
```

more info please refer to NSDataformatter.